# Airbnb style guide:rules for naming conventions not working

Tags: javascript, eslint, airbnb-js-styleguide, eslintrc

According to the Airbnb doc, this is the best practice for naming objects

```
// bad
const OBJEcttsssss = {};

// good
const thisIsMyObject = {};
```

But which rule I need to add to achieve the same

Here is my `.eslintrc.json`

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "rules":{
    "camelcase":true
  }
}
```

I've added `camelcase` rule but it didn't work

Also, I can't find the rules belong to the following

1) Variable naming
2) Function naming
3) Class Naming

Answer (score 0):

You are  not defining the rule correctly it need to be an array

eg : `"camelcase": [2, {"properties": "always"}]`

More info about the options there :
https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/camelcase